# Remove extra white spaces in a string created with @

Tags: c#, xslt

I am creating a transformation string as following:

```
string transform = @"
              <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
                <xsl:stylesheet version='1.0' xmlns:xsl='http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform'
                xmlns:msxsl='urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt' exclude-result-prefixes='msxsl'>
                <xsl:template match='*'>
                <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:for-each select='@*|*[not(* or @*)]'>
                <xsl:attribute name='{name(.)}'><xsl:value-of select='.'/>
                </xsl:attribute>
                </xsl:for-each>
                <xsl:apply-templates select='*[* or @*]|text()'/>
                </xsl:copy>
                </xsl:template>
                </xsl:stylesheet>
            ";
```

When I am loading it I am getting this error:
{"Unexpected XML declaration. The XML declaration must be the first node in the document, and no white space characters are allowed to appear before it. Line 2, position 21."}
As I understand it complains about white spaces in a front of a new line. So, what's the idea here? Should I remove extra white spaces? If I copy that string into an xslt processor it works fine.

Thanks for help.

Comment: I tried, does not seem to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's complaining about the portion of the string between `@"` and the first `<`. All other whitespace in your transform will be ignored.

A cheap way to fix it would be moving `@"` to the next line:

```
string transform =
        @"<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
            <xsl:stylesheet version='1.0' xmlns:xsl='http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform'
            xmlns:msxsl='urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt' exclude-result-prefixes='msxsl'>
            ...
            </xsl:stylesheet>
        ";
```

Alternatively you could call `Trim()` on your verbatim string:

```
string transform = @"
          <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
            <xsl:stylesheet version='1.0' xmlns:xsl='http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform'
            xmlns:msxsl='urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt' exclude-result-prefixes='msxsl'>
            ...
            </xsl:stylesheet>
        ".Trim();
```

but you would no longer be able to make `transform` a `const string`.

Comment: Yes, that was it. Thanks